# Defining Show on an arbitrary recursive type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to make a custom type an instance of Show.

Here's theType, it's just a basic Set type.

```
data Set a = Insert a (Set a) | EmptySet
```

I'd like something like

```
Insert 1 (Insert 2 (Insert 3 EmptySet))
```

to display like

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

How do I do this? I tried doing it with string concatenation, but it seems like doing string interpolation is considered bad form (Haskell doesn't seem to natively support this?) Also, how do I get the curly braces around the list? So far, all I was able to cook up was this, which basically does nothing...

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Set a) where
     show EmptySet = ""
     show (Insert a as) = show a ++ show as
```

Also, I tried to use Hoogle and Hayoo to find the List implementation so I could see how this was implemented on Lists. I couldn't find it. Does anyone have any pointers on this? I tried searching "show::[a]->String", "Data.Lists", "Lists" etc....

Comment: By the way, this is probably a bad idea. The result of `show` should be valid Haskell code that produces a value equal to the one passed to `show`. I suggest defining a `fromList` function and making `show` on the set {1, 2, 3} produce e.g. `fromList [1, 2, 3]`; this is the approach taken by the standard Data.Map and Data.Set libraries. Alternatively, you could define your own function that does this to be called instead of `show` to view sets in this notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution with direct recursion:

```
instance Show a => Show (Set a) where
  show = ('{' :) . go
    where
      go EmptySet            = "}"
      go (Insert x EmptySet) = show x ++ "}"
      go (Insert x xs)       = show x ++ ", " ++ go xs
```

If you don't like the inefficient use of `(++)`, you can of course use [difference lists](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list):

```
instance Show a => Show (Set a) where
  show = ('{' :) . ($ []) . go
    where
      go EmptySet            = ('}' :)
      go (Insert x EmptySet) = shows x . ('}' :)
      go (Insert x xs)       = shows x . (", " ++) . go xs
```

That should do it; so, let's test:

```
> show (Insert 2 (Insert 3 (Insert 5 EmptySet)))
"{2, 3, 5}"
```

Comment: If you don't like the inefficient use of `(++)` you should implement `showsPrec` instead of `show`.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: I agree, of course, but I wanted to demonstrate the delta with the first implementation.

Answer (score 5):

That type of yours is still homomorphic to a list.  Wherever that `Show` instance is defined; you can still use it:

```
toList (Insert a b) = a:toList b
toList EmptySet = []

instance Show a => Show (Set a) where
    show = show . toList
```

Answer (score 4):

The data type might be recursive, but that's no reason for the function to be recursive.

```
import Data.List (intercalate)

instance Show a => Show (Set a) where
  show x = "{" ++ intercalate ", " (toList x) ++ "}"
```

This assumes you have a function `toList :: Set a -> [a]`. The recursion is hidden in there.

The List implementation is done via the `showList` function from the [`Show` typeclass](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Show.html#Show) (so that `String`s, a.k.a. `[Char]`s, can be displayed differently).

Comment: I'm kind of a noob, but doesn't this break because a list has to contain elements of all the same type? If I feed a list of numbers into this function, won't it barf a type error?

Comment: The set as you've defined it also has to contain elements of the same type. In `Insert a (Set a)`, it's all `a`s. So there shouldn't be a problem.